# execute a banged git-alias (!"tricky-functions here") with a different shell

Tags: bash, git, alias

I have recently started using a system where `/bin/sh --help` reports an old version of bash.

```
$ /bin/sh --help
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin18)
```

This affects some of my my bash-aliases because I like to define them with dashes.

```
$ grep coi ~/.gitconfig; git coi
    coi = !"function foo-bar() { true; }; foo-bar"
function foo-bar() { true; }; foo-bar: `foo-bar': not a valid identifier
```

So bash-3 does not handle dashes in function names.

How do I tell git to run a different shell, e.g. /usr/local/bin/bash5 to execute complex aliases?